# Can't use latest Java Version (JDK 21) in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-21

I'm using macOS and I want to try Java 21 in Intellij IDEA. I believe I have done all the required steps to change Java version of a project / module. Nevertheless I still can't use new Java 21 Features, such as [String Templates](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430). How to be able to use Java 21 in Intellij?

[image]

I have changed:

- Project SDK to 21
- Module SDK to 21
- OS java version to 21. Typing `java -version` in terminal outputs:

  > java version "21" 2023-09-19 LTS
  >
  > Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21+35-LTS-2513)
  >
  > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-LTS-2513, mixed mode, sharing)
- I have also updated Intellij to version 2023.2

Comment: Have you set the language level to "21 (Preview)"?

Comment: Language Level 21 didn't show up because my Intellij was only on version 2023.2. I needed to update it to 2023.2.2 to be able to use Language Level 21

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I needed to update Intellij version to 2023.2.2 and change Language level (File -> Project structure -> project -> language level) to 21 (preview)

[image: language level 21 (preview)]
The new language level won't show up until Intellij is updated to the latest version.

To update Intellij, I needed to manually check for new update

**Manually updating Intellij on Mac**

Intellij IDEA | Check for Updates

[image]

**Manually updating Intellij on Windows / Linux**

File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Updates

[image]

Comment: Yes, see the single sentence about JDK-21 in https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/09/intellij-idea-2023-2-2/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nicolas' answer, if you have a Maven project you should also add the build plugin, shown below, to the `pom.xml`.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>21</source>
                <target>21</target>
                <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used those steps after upgrading to latest Intellij release:

1. Right click on the module and choose 'Open Module Settings'
2. Choose SDKs and Add whatever ( Download JDK, Add JDK, or select from
   detected list)
3. On the same popup menu, Go to project and
   select your desired SDK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed a few options mentioned above, but nothing worked.
The main problem was that the Gradle plugin was configured to use an older JDK version.
I had to change it in the below settings to use JDK-21.
After changing the JDK here, then everything worked fine.

[image: Gradle Settings]

Answer (score 0):

At first I installed Oracle jdk from https://www.oracle.com/ae/java/technologies/downloads/
and tried everything above which progressed me to the stage where compile/run/verify was working from Maven command line or plugin but not from IntelliJ ( 2023.3.4 - Community Edition).

At last, re-downloading Oracle OpenJDK 21 from Intelli-J itself fixed them too.

[Clicke here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjO9s.png)