# IntelliJ IDEA + JDK 21 issue with java.util.concurrent package - TimeUnit class not available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.concurrent, java-21

I have an issue when I am trying to use TimeUnit class from java.util.concurrent. It happens with **Oracle JDK 21.0.1** (configurations are below) + **IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.5** (Community Edition) - *the latest update at the current moment (UPDATE: As I thought in the beginning since I've run update - look a solution below).*

Configuration on my computer (get by *java -version* in console):

> java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)

And I've checked that I set up JDK 21 in IntelliJ Project Structure menu including Project and Modules sections.

On the screenshot below you can see a basic class created for test purposes. Some concurrent package classes are imported fine, but not `TimeUnit` class for some reason.

[image: The issue screenshot]

Meanwhile you can see on the screenshot that app works despite the issue when I run it.

When I am using java 17 in IDE configurations, I don't see the issue.

**Could you please help to understand why this issue happens and how to fix it?**

One more thing. When I go to "About IntelliJ IDEA" menu, I see the next configuration:

> Runtime version: 17.0.7+10-b829.16 aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
> VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

I am not sure why it says version 17, **could it be a reason of the issue?**

Comment: Looks like an IntelliJ cache problem. Try removing the out directory and rebuild it again, if that doesn't help try to invalidate the IntelliJ cache and restart.

Comment: Actually, I've tried to invalidate caches and recreated .idea folder, but it didn't help. As I mentioned in the answer, only IntelliJ update to the last version fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While searching, I found a solution.

Following [the same kind of issue discussed in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141340/cant-use-latest-java-version-jdk-21-in-intellij-idea), I manually updated IntelliJ to version 2023.2.5 one more time, and now the issue is resolved.

**It appears that when updating IntelliJ, it may be necessary to perform the update process multiple times consecutively.**

Comment: [Invalidating caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html) might be a less drastic solution.

Comment: Actually, I've tried to invalidate caches and recreated .idea folder, but it didn't help. As I mentioned in the answer, only IntelliJ update to the last version fixed this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, but unfortunately I cannot update IntelliJ.

Comment: @BasilBourque tried your propose. Invalidate caches did not help

Comment: Tip: I have had good luck with deleting any copies of IntelliJ that were manually installed, then uso only [*JetBrains Toolbox*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) for automatic installs and updates of IntelliJ (and any other JetBrains apps).